# How is Lagrange's $2\sqrt{D}$ bound on partial denominators proven for periodic regular continued fractions of quadratic irrationals

Tags: reference-request, proof-writing, quadratics, continued-fractions

For the quadratic surd:

$$
\zeta = \dfrac{P + \sqrt D}Q
$$

the wikipedia article on [periodic continued fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_continued_fraction#Length_of_the_repeating_block) mentions that Lagrange proves that the largest partial denominator of a regular continued fraction for $\zeta$ is less than $2\sqrt D$.  I also note that for this continued fraction:

$$
\sqrt D = [a_0;\overline{a_1,a_2,\dots a_2,a_1,2a_0}]
$$
and
$$
2a_0 = 2\lfloor\sqrt D\rfloor < 2\sqrt D
$$

which would seem to be a clue to the bound, as $2a_0$ is close to but less than the bound.  However, that pattern is only shown for $\sqrt D$, not for quadratic surds in general.  So how was this bound derived and proven by Lagrange?  I haven't found anything pertinent on Google or other math sites explaining this.

**Edit**

In light of the fact a large $P$ would seem to disconnect the size of $a_0$ from the size of $2D$, I'm going to assume that Wikipedia stated this poorly, and was only making a statement about $\sqrt D$.  In that case, how is the $2\sqrt D$ bound proven for $\sqrt D$?

Comment: I know how to do it if $\zeta$ is reduced, and i suspect it may be false, for just the initial non-repeating portion, if $\zeta$ is not reduced. Most detail in Leonard Eugene Dickson, Introduction to the  Theory of Numbers (1929). Similar, and easier to read, in Buell, Binary Quadratic Forms. See my post at http://math.blogoverflow.com/2014/08/

Comment: Thank you for the references.  I also suspect it might be false for the initial aperiodic portion, and was surprised at the statement on Wikipedia, but I would like to know for certain.

Comment: If you take their $P$ arbitrarily large, the $a_0$ is also large, with fixed $D.$ Less sure after that.

Comment: I've edited the question to apply only for $\sqrt D$.  Can you demonstrate the proof for this case?  I saw your blog post, but I would like something less lengthy to work through. :-)  Is the proof for reduced form very involved?

Comment: The only line that matters is $$   |\delta| = \; \left\lfloor \; \frac{B + \left\lfloor \sqrt \Delta \right\rfloor }{2|C|}  \; \right\rfloor .  $$ Here we would have $ \sqrt \Delta = 2 \sqrt D, $ also $B < \sqrt \Delta $

Comment: As I recall, it took me several lectures of introductory material before I couold give the proof you want. Better skip the web, go to the library, get a good intro Number Theory textbook with a chapter on continued fractions of quadratic irrationals.

Comment: In that case, do you know of any texts that specifically cover this?  My library is not the best stocked, but I could probably inter-library loan something.

Comment: @Gerry is quite correct. I can recommend a new book by friends of his, Neverending Fractions, inexpensive  http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/number-theory/neverending-fractions-introduction-continued-fractions  . Meanwhile, my comment with $\delta$ is about reduced forms; however, if $a_0 = \lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor,$ then $a_0 + \sqrt n$ is a reduced surd. The relation between my stuff and simple continued fractions amounts to my $\delta$'s being, in absolute value, the partial denominators

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I will consider ordering it.  The topics covered look very interesting in and of themselves.  I just saw that Amazon has a Kindle edition for $20!